# Multiple-instance Django forum software

Tags: python, django, forum

Does anyone know of a django forum plugin that allows each member to have his own forum? If there isn't anything, than what would be the best way to accomplish this with a "regular" forum plugin for Django?

Answer (score 4):

I once created a [feature matrix](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ForumAppsComparison) of all Django forum apps I could find. It might be a bit outdated now, though (contributions welcome).

At least django-threadedcomments uses generic foreign keys, so you can attach a message thread to any database object, including users.

Comment: Yeah, I've been thinking about using threadedcomments... just didn't know if there was a drop-in solution for multiple users. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Look at [DjangoBB](http://djangobb.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Yep, the [forum app of SCT](http://sct.sphene.net/) can be used for this - simply set it up and create multiple "community Groups" (these are similar to vhosts) and map them to subdomains - each community group would have separate forum categories, can have separate templates, separate user permissions, etc. (but they will obviously share the same django users and their profiles) - as an example.. the following websites are all hosted on the same instance:

- [SCT website](http://sct.sphene.net/)
- [My personal website/blog](http://herbert.poul.at/) (the blog is also based on SCTs forum)
- [ShelfShare Community](http://shelfshare-community.sphene.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [diamanda](http://djangoplugables.com/projects/diamanda/). I'm not sure it does what you need as far as the each user having its forums, but that's probably not too hard to hack on top.  Probably as simple as adding a few ForeignKeys into auth.User to the diamanda models.  In general [django pluggables](http://djangoplugables.com/) and [djangoapps](http://djangoapps.org/) are good places to look for django stuff that is already written.  Also, check out [pinax](http://cloud27.com/).

Comment: @rz you got your link markup the wrong way, links do not show.

Comment: argh! thanks for noticing, akaihola, sometimes when i post in a hurry...
it should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [Sphene Community Tools](http://sct.sphene.net/wiki/show/Board/) can do this.